# Is the infinite product of {0, 1} countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

In my math class, we had an exercise asking us to prove that the following set is not countable:
$$\prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0,1\} = \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times \cdots$$
By Cantor's diagonalization argument, we can show that
$$f : \mathbb{N} \to \prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0,1\}$$
defined by $f(n) = (b_{1_n}, b_{2_n}, \cdots)$ is not surjective if we fix some $q = (q_1, q_2, q_3, \cdots)  \in \prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0, 1\}$ where
$$q_i = \begin{cases}
1 & \operatorname{if} ~ b_{i_i} = 0 \\
0 & \operatorname{if} ~ b_{i_i} = 1
\end{cases}$$
(i.e., the $n$th element of $q$ is opposite of the $n$th element of $f(n)$), which would mean that $x \neq f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0, 1\}$ is uncountable.

However, it seems possible to define a bijection for $f: \mathbb{N} \to \prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0, 1\}$ if we define $f(n)$ to be an ordered tuple representing the coefficients of the binary expansion of $n -1$. For example:
$$
0 = 0 \cdot 2^0 + 0 \cdot 2^1 + 0 \cdot 2^2 + \cdots \\
1 = 1 \cdot 2^0 + 0 \cdot 2^1 + 0 \cdot 2^2 + \cdots  \\
2 = 0 \cdot 2^0 + 1 \cdot 2^1 + 0 \cdot 2^2 + \cdots \\
3 = 1 \cdot 2^0 + 1 \cdot 2^1 + 0 \cdot 2^2 + \cdots \\
n = a_{n_0} \cdot 2^0 + a_{n_1} \cdot 2^1 + a_{n_2} \cdot 2^2 + \cdots 
$$
So then we could define $f: \mathbb{N} \to \prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0,1\}$ by
$$f(k) = (a_{k-1_0}, a_{k-1_1}, a_{k-1_2}, \cdots)$$
which would give us
$$
f(1) = (0, 0, 0, \cdots) \quad \text{(the coefficients of the binary expansion of 0)}\\
f(2) = (1, 0, 0, \cdots) \quad \text{(the coefficients of the binary expansion of 1)} \\
f(3) = (0, 1, 0, \cdots) \quad \text{(the coefficients of the binary expansion of 2)} \\
f(4) = (1, 1, 0, \cdots) \quad \text{(the coefficients of the binary expansion of 3)} \\
f(n + 1) = (a_{n_0}, a_{n_1}, a_{n_2}, \cdots) \quad \text{(the coefficients of the binary expansion of n)}
$$
(Note: I use $k$ and $k - 1$ to preserve the domain of $\mathbb{N}$, but it is trivial to prove that $|\mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}| = |\mathbb{N}|$. Also, assume that more significant coefficients omitted by the ellipses are an infinite number of zeros.)

In my mind, $f$ would be injective because every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ would have a unique binary expansion comprised of only 0s and 1s as coefficients (hence, the basis for the base-2 number system working), and $f$ would be surjective because we can turn a tuple of coefficients back into a base-10 integer. (i.e., $(b_0, b_1, b_2, \cdots)$ would translate directly to ${\dots b_2 b_1 b_0}_2 = n = k - 1$.) Thus we've established a bijection that allows us to conclude that $|\mathbb{N}| = |\prod \limits^\infty_{i=1} \{0, 1\}|$, making it countable.

Would this disprove Cantor's diagonalization argument for this instance, or are there flaws to the binary expansion argument?

*Reference: Doud, Darrin, and Pace P. Nielsen. “Exercise 30.6.” A Transition to Advanced Mathematics, Provo, Utah, 2022, p. 231.*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142859/discussion-on-question-by-joseph-is-the-infinite-product-of-0-1-countable); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.